# gcc on Windows: generated "a.exe" file vanishes

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I'm using GCC version 4.7.1, but I've also tried this on GCC 4.8. Here is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int amount) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d", i);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    print(5);
    return 0;
}
```

It looks like it should work, and when I compile with...

```
gcc main.c
```

It takes a while to compile, produces an `a.exe` file and the the `a.exe` file disappears. It isn't giving me any errors with my code.

Here's a gif of proof, as some people are misinterpreting this:
[image: proof]

Comment: Have you some antivirus installed? Try disabling it and let us know.

Comment: Moved it to my desktop and tried compiling it there, same result again

Comment: The third window is Sublime Text 3

Comment: OK, a terminological train wreck. gcc probably has nothing to do with this. Look at your system logs and antivirus logs.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Spot on, strange since it will usually warn me if it quarantines or flags a file. I'm using Avast Antivirus, if that helps.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to stop avast from blacklisting my code :(

Comment: Actually [ahoffer's deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24661481/827263) isn't *quite* correct; it suggests that the file name `a.exe` is the problem. In fact virus scanners check the contents of files, not their names. (In this case, it's a false positive.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Some malware scanners do delete files based on their names (more as a simple-minded way of making it hard to install software not approved by central IT than as a way to remove actual malware).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Since ahoffer's [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24661481/827263) isn't quite correct, I'll post this, based on information in the comments.)

On Windows, gcc generates an executable named `a.exe` by default. (On UNIX-like systems, the default name, for historical reasons, is `a.out`.) Normally you'd specify a name using the `-o` option.

Apparently the generated `a.exe` file generates a false positive match in your antivirus software, so the file is automatically deleted shortly after it's created. I see you've already [contacted](http://www.avast.com/contact-form.php) the developers of Avast about this false positive.

Note that antivirus programs typically check the *contents* of a file, not its name, so generating the file with a name other than `a.exe` won't help. Making some changes to the program might change the contents of the executable enough to avoid the problem, though.

You might try compiling a simple "hello, world" program to see if the same thing happens.

Thanks to Chrono Kitsune for linking to [this relevant Mingw-users discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/38529) in a comment.

This is not relevant to your problem, but you should print a newline (`'\n'`) at the end of your program's output. It probably doesn't matter much in your Windows environment, but in general a program's standard output should (almost) *always* have a newline character at the end of its last line.

Answer (score 4):

Try to compile with gcc but without all standard libraries using a command like this:

```
gcc  -nostdlib -c  test.c -o test.o; gcc test.o -lgcc -o test.exe
```

One of the mingw libraries binary must generate a false positive, knowing which library would be useful.

Comment: I've faced the same problem and compiling my file this way helped. Any idea about how could I narrow down which library is causing a problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is no issue with your code it is just exiting properly.

You have to run it in the command line which will show you all the info.

start->run->cmd, then `cd` to your directory. then a.exe. If you don't want to do that you can add a sleep() before the return in main.

More over, in your code when you pass `print(5)` to your function it's not being used.

Comment: While I was attempting to solve the solution, I changed the for loop to loop from 0 to 5 rather than 0, to amount. Also I am running it in the command line. And I can't run a.exe if it's not there.

Comment: I see I mis-read your question. It says a.exe is disappearing, not the terminal window. My apologies.

Comment: I think you're onto something though, since I printed some text after calling the `print(int)` function, and it executes fine. Any ideas?

Comment: try adding -O0 flag and see if that does anything. GCC could be optimizing everything out for some ungodly reason.

Comment: Same result, again :(

Comment: Try adding a \n after the %d to force a flush on stdout

Comment: Tried that, same result still.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm is due to Antivirus. 
I did this test: 
compile helloworld.c at t=0; 
within 1 second tell McAfee not consider helloworld.exe a threat. >> the file is still there
If I am too slow, the file will be deleted.

[image: Antivirus next to compilation instructions]

Answer (score -1):

If suppose you get the error  near a.exe while running the file ,
Theen follow the below steps:
1.open virus & threat protection
2.there select manage settings in virus & threat protection settings
3.there is real time protection and cloud delivered protection is in ON then OFF the real time protection and cloud delivered protection.!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcIio.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

a.exe is also the name of a virus. I suspect your computer's security software is deleting or quarantining the file because it believes it is a virus. Use redFIVE's suggestion to rename your output file to "print.exe" so that the virus scanner does not delete it.

Comment: I tried redFives suggestion and it didn't work. Also my antivirus would notify me if it were to quarantine a file.

Answer (score -2):

You try:

```
gcc -o YOUR_PROGRAM.exe main.c
```

Comment: It is customary to provide commentary along with your "code".

Answer (score -2):

You can stop your antivirus software from deleting your .exe by specifying the full file path (for eg: c:\MyProject) in the 'paths to be excluded from scanning' section of the antivirus software.