# Executable file being deleted after compilation

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I'm trying to compile a C code, but just after the compilation is done it's automatically deleted without returning any error. I alredy tried to disable the antivirus as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661377/gcc-on-windows-generated-a-exe-file-vanishes) says and it didn't work.
The code I'm compiling is :

```
while(fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, inptr) == 512) {
        if (file_number != 0 && buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && buffer[3] >= 0xe0 && buffer[3] <= 0xef) {
            fclose(outptr);
            get_file_name(file_number, file_name);
            outptr = fopen(file_name, "w");
        }
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, outptr);
    }
    fclose(inptr);
```

Note: I'm compiling using

```
gcc recover.c -o recover
```

And there is no message after compilation as the image show:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a log of the exact commands you are running to compile and check the file. Also, try with a "hello world" program to reduce to the simplest test case.

Comment: I updated the question with the commando used for compilation, and yes, the hello world works just fine.

Comment: `The code I'm compiling is` where is `main`? Don't you get compiler errors? How do you know the file is deleted? How do you know the file is created in the first place?

Comment: Please show the full log. Include any compiler output and how you are checking that the file has been deleted.

Comment: Yes, it is inside `main`. I posted just the important part, the rest was only variable declarations and command line arguments filtering

Comment: @kaylum I can see that the file is deleted because i see it been created and disapearing, just like on the gif ate the question i mentioned. But the answer to that question didn't worked for me

Comment: Likely unrelated, but recover is already a windows command, give your program a different name.

Comment: I thought about that, tried renaiming it and it didn't work. But ii Found the solution, on the `get_file_name` function I was using the `itoa()` function. I don't know why, but replacing it with a `sptinf()` stopped the error

Comment: `itoa` is not part of the standard, replacing it is a good measure, regardless. Still, I can't see why it was causing the exe to be deleted.